# How do I get my keyboard back?

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, keyboard

I recently got an Android Polaroid tablet and I noticed it was incredibly slow so I disabled and force stopped a lot of the apps that were pre-downloaded onto the device because I knew I'd never need them. That seemed to help and for a few weeks everything was cool and way faster until I started getting this notification every two seconds that said, "*Unfortunately, Android Keyboard has stopped.*"

A little bit after that, I went back to college and I tried to connect to my school's WiFi and it wouldn't work because you need to type in a username and password to connect, and you can't type without a keyboard. So, I know you can install keyboards onto your tablet to replace the old one, but

1. I can't connect to WiFi without typing,
2. I can't connect to Google Play without WiFi, and
3. Even if I could, how would I search for keyboard apps without being able to type them in?

Comment: You could re-enable the apps you force stopped, until your device is restored to functionality, with your working keyboard, then disable slowly and carefully until you reach an acceptable state again?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I think on my Apps list in Settings after I force stopped them they all went away

Comment: The (Settings > Applications) applist on your device, if it sticks to convention, is in 3 panels. View "All" panel at the far right, and find the disabled apps at the bottom of the list there. Select each in turn and use the button to "Enable", "Turn On" or whatever similar terminology is used.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect your device via USB to push an apk from the computer. There are a number of sites that allow apk files to be downloaded to a pc and file transferred this way. Search google for "android keyboard apk download" for an acceptable one. Once the file has been placed in a folder on the device, double click it to run "Package Installer" to install. You will have to enable the setting "Unknown Sources" in the security panel to install this way.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll definitely try that, I'll just have to get a mini USB adapter first

Comment: The mini USB adapter is the same used to power the device. Unless you have a power-only plug, it will have a detachable cord with USB already at the other end. That will connect your device to the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. I used the "touch" to copy and paste the word keyboard into playstore. If you cant get wifi because you cannot VOICE it in. Then VOICE your information into Google. Copy. Paste. Hope you solve this is terrible when it happens!
I was hoping someone could just tell me the app I accidentally flipped off... Literally and. Figuratively!

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can install new keyboard via recovery.
i don't know what your device is, but you could try install this keyboard.

you could use this
["get the flashable zip here"](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1964663)

go to recovery and install it.
good luck.

Comment: Where can I find Recovery on my device? I have a Polaroid Tablet

Answer (score -1):

Go to Google play, push another keyboard apps to your mobile from any pc or notebook, after installing newly installed keyboard app set it as default, then from setting make google keyboard as default, you will get the keyboard back....... .........

Comment: This will only work if the device is connected to a WiFi or a data network, which it doesn't seem they have access to.